# MAIL FROM command missing

Tags: evolution, command-line, mail

I am trying to send mail from Evolution and get this message: `MAIL FROM command failed: No identity changes permitted. lc1sm14589093qeb.5 - gsmtp`

Any clues what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is an error from your mail server so you will need to contact the admin of your mail server to find out more, but it sounds like it won't let you claim to be sending mail from an address that differs from the one you are supposed to be using.